# How to add different subtypes as a drop-down menu to different fields within the same Feature Class?

Tags: arcpy, subtype

I'm trying to add different drop-down menus to a feature class' attribute table for someone creating polygons within that feature class to choose from. Different fields will have different drop-down menus. Any ideas?

```
from arcpy import env
circuit_short_name = "Line"
county = "Place"

projectfilepath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Projects\\ARCPY_test\\"
projectfileGDB = county + "_County_" + circuit_short_name + ".gdb"

env.workspace = projectfilepath + projectfileGDB

in_table = circuit_short_name + "_Polygons"
default_value = 0

try:
    arcpy.management.SetSubtypeField(in_table, "OpCo")
    arcpy.management.SetSubtypeField(in_table, "RightsType")
    arcpy.management.SetSubtypeField(in_table, "Type_of_Use")

    stypeDict = {"0": "Choose", "1": "ME", "2": "IT", "3": "ITA", "4": "Choose", 
                 "5": "Easement", "6": "Fee", "7": "License",
                 "8": "Choose", "9": "Full T-Line", "10": "Substation", "11": "Railroad", "12": "Overhang Only", 
                 "13": "Vegetation Management Only", "14": "Access", "15": "Other"
                 }

    for code in stypeDict:
        arcpy.management.AddSubtype(in_table, code, stypeDict[code])   
    arcpy.management.SetDefaultSubtype(in_table, default_value)


    subtype_code = ["0: Choose", "1: MET", "2: IT", "3: ITA"]
    arcpy.management.AssignDefaultToField(in_table, "OpCo", default_value, subtype_code, "DO_NOT_CLEAR")


    subtype_code_2 = ["0: Choose", "5: Easement", "6: Fee", "7: License"]
    arcpy.management.AssignDefaultToField(in_table, "RightsType", default_value, subtype_code_2, "DO_NOT_CLEAR")


    subtype_code_3 = ["0: Choose", "8: Full T-Line", "9: Substation", "10: Railroad", "12: Overhang Only", 
                     "13: Vegetation Management Only", "14: Access", "15: Other"
                     ]
    arcpy.management.AssignDefaultToField(in_table, "Type_of_Use", default_value, subtype_code_3, "DO_NOT_CLEAR")

 except Exception as err:
    print(err.args[0])
```

Comment: As said by @Daniel a feature class or table can have only one subtype field but you can set different domain for each subtype....

Comment: What would setting a domain do? (What is setting a domain?)

Comment: A domain is a list of value to choose from (see : https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/help/data/geodatabases/overview/an-overview-of-attribute-domains.htm) and from your question it seem that's what you want. Subtype (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/help/data/geodatabases/overview/an-overview-of-subtypes.htm) let you use several domain for the same field (a domain for each subtype) so you may want to use subtype and domain

Comment: It appears to me that subtype and domain are inextricably linked, and I'm not sure how to approach. However, I appreciate the bump: thanks J.R.!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Domains are the way to go! Thank you @J.R. for the heads-up.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-domain.htm

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/assign-domain-to-field.htm

Below is an example that worked wonderfully. I just copied the basic form from Esri and tweaked until it worked:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = projectfilepath + projectfileGDB
# Set local parameters
domName = "OpCo_Domain"
domain_description = "OpCo Choices"
gdb = projectfilepath + projectfileGDB
inFeatures = projectfilepath + projectfileGDB + "\\" + circuit_short_name + "_Polygons"
inField = "OpCo"

# Process: Create the coded value domain
arcpy.management.CreateDomain(gdb, domName, domain_description, "TEXT", "CODED")

# Store all the domain values in a dictionary with the domain code as the "key" 
# and the domain description as the "value" (domDict[code])
domDict = {"0": "Choose", "1": "MET", "2": "IT", "3": "ITA"}
    
# Process: Add valid material types to the domain
# use a for loop to cycle through all the domain codes in the dictionary
for code in domDict:        
    arcpy.management.AddCodedValueToDomain(gdb, domName, code, domDict[code])
    
# Process: Constrain the material value of distribution mains
arcpy.management.AssignDomainToField(inFeatures, inField, domName)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that according to Esri "a feature class or table can have only one subtype field."

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/set-subtype-field.htm